# Getting error while calling mysql-workbench but solved

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried to install Mysql workbench through terminal but gave me following error:

$ mysql-workbench
Found /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15
/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.23: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE

Actually, I tried to install it using Ubuntu software center, but on clicking the local instance, it would give an error that it could not connect to database, therefore I tried to install it with terminal after uninstalling from the software center.

Then, again I tried to install it using Ubuntu software center, a permissions tab was there alongside the 'remove', after clicking it a toggle of ~'read and edit password' was turned off, I turned it on, it asked for user login password and then, MySQL workbench was able to open the local instance.

Comment: You might need to reinstall the mysql workbench. See other questions like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201645/mysql-workbench-cannot-open-symbol-lookup-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, install MySQL Workbench using Ubuntu's Software center only, but make sure to give it permissions to read and edit password just after installation in software center itself only

Comment: First of all uninstall all previously installed versions. Ensure you have a running mysql server installation. Then use the Software center(Search on your pc apps for: *Ubuntu Software* app) as stated above, and click on the permissions button, below the mysql workbench icon, then select the permissions you need. --Tested on Ubuntu 20.04lts